# Can I open .ftl in browser directly without going through the app cycle?

Tags: java, html, keycloak

I am creating a custom theme using Keycloak and for every page that I edit, I have to go through some process to reach that page. Is there a way to directly open some particular page and edit it out of the box?

Example: If I want to edit the page where it shows that the password was updated successfully, I have to go through a process of resetting the password each time.

I have made edits in the standalone.xml which edits the page on every refresh, but there are some pages that have a timeout limit and if I make the edit, come back to the browser, the only thing I can do is to "Go back to login". Then same story, reset the password and reach that page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no you can't. I'm in the same pain as you). At least you can greatly increase timeout in Admin console for debugging purposes. If you would like to go deeper, you can implement JAX-RS endpoint SPI that will expose all .ftl pages but will exclude underlying business logic, so any buttons or links will not trigger redirects.